# Webpack on Windows fails loading plugins

Tags: angularjs, node.js, windows, webpack, webpack-dev-server

Good evening,

I'm working on a project written in NodeJS. It uses an express server and many other dependencies like angular, googlemaps, tika, karma, etc.
A few weeks ago I've got the order to make the webpage (localhost) faster by implementing webpack. It bundles all stylesheets and scripts into one file.

After a lot of work to solve all dependencies I've got the app running even though many errors couldn't be found with google. e.g. "java" is a sub dependency which calls "node-gyp rebuild" which is doomed to failure on windows because node-gyp need python and c++ compiler. After installing Windows SDK, VS 2015, etc. I could fix this problem switching to the 32 bit version of node (instead of 64 bit).
After repairing all dependencies I switched to the 64 bit version to solve another problem. The webpack config is due to the amount of dependencies (which needs "alias" entries) quite long.

Two weeks ago I started to implement a developer mode so you can change code and webpack-dev-server automatically rebuilds the bundle file. Therefore I followed a tutorial from [SurviveJS](http://survivejs.com/webpack_react/developing_with_webpack/).

I've got it easily running after the tutorial. But for a presentation I wanted to clone the Github repository and install all dependencies a second time so I can be sure that the project works. But this time a new error appeared when I was running webpack or webpack-dev-server which couldn't be solved with my previous tricks:

```
Path_to_project\demo\n2o>..\node_modules\.bin\webpack --config webpack.config.js
Error: No module factory available for dependency type: ModuleDependency
    at Compilation.addModuleDependencies (Path_to_project\demo\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:181:20)
    at Compilation.processModuleDependencies (Path_to_project\demo\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:170:7)
    at Compilation.moduleReady (Path_to_project\demo\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:412:9)
    at Compilation.<anonymous> (Path_to_project\demo\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:408:16)
    at Path_to_project\demo\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:123:4
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at callback (Path_to_project\demo\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:122:12)
    at Compilation.<anonymous> (Path_to_project\demo\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:140:10)
    at DependenciesBlock.<anonymous> (Path_to_project\demo\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:115:10)
    at DependenciesBlock.onModuleBuild (Path_to_project\demo\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\webpack-core\lib\NormalModuleMixin.js:310:10)
    at nextLoader (Path_to_project\demo\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\webpack-core\lib\NormalModuleMixin.js:275:25)
    at Path_to_project\demo\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\webpack-core\lib\NormalModuleMixin.js:259:5
    at Storage.finished (Path_to_project\demo\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:38:16)
    at Path_to_project\demo\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:76:16
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:380:3)
```

When I remove all plugins from the webpack config the error disappears but obviously running the app fails because the angular-webpack-plugin is missing and most of the dependencies are not loaded by webpack. What could be the reason for this failure? I tried different versions of webpack (1.12.2 worked out for me after discovering this fix in an issue on Github) and webpack-dev-server.

I would appreciate your help,
Thomas Kellermeier

Files (webpack.config.js, package.json):

1. webpack.config.js (webpack)

The settings for webpack-dev-server are at the end of the config

```
    var path = require('path');
    var AngularPlugin = require('angular-webpack-plugin');
    var webpack = require("webpack");
    require("css-selector-tokenizer");
    var merge = require('webpack-merge');

    const TARGET = process.env.npm_lifecycle_event;

    common = {
        entry: 'n2o',
        output: {
            path: 'public/app',
            filename: 'n2o.min.js',
            publicPath: 'app/'
        },
        externals: {
                "jquery": "jQuery"
        },
        resolve: {
            root: [
                // Directories containing modules
                path.resolve('public'),
                  path.resolve('public', 'assets/libs'),
                path.resolve('public', 'components'),
                path.resolve('public', 'components/settings'),
                path.resolve('public', 'components/splitapp'),
                path.resolve('public', 'components/register'),
                path.resolve('public', 'shared/postContent'),
                path.resolve('public', 'shared'),
                // Needed for webpack-dev-server modules
                path.resolve('public', '../../node_modules')
            ],
              modulesDirectories:['public/assets/libs'],
              'dev-tool':'eval',
            alias: {
                // Replace module names with belonging file names
                n2o$: 'app.module',
                ngFileUpload$: 'ng-file-upload',
                toaster$: 'angularjs-toaster',
                ngCookies$: 'angular-cookies',
                  'ui.router$': __dirname+'/public/assets/libs/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js',
                  'jQuery$': __dirname+'/public/assets/libs/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
                registration$: 'register',
                ngAnimate$: 'angular-animate',
                'mm.foundation$': __dirname+'/public/assets/libs/angular-foundation/mm-foundation.js',
                vcRecaptcha$:'angular-recaptcha',
                filters$: 'postContentController',
                'cfp.hotkeys$':'angular-hotkeys',
                'angulartics.google.analytics$':__dirname+'/public/assets/libs/angulartics/dist/angulartics-ga.min.js',
                splitapp$:'splitappController',
                register$:'registerController',
                'ngTouch$':'angular-touch',
                'ui-rangeSlider$':__dirname+'/public/assets/libs/angular-rangeslider/angular.rangeSlider.js',
                ngSanitize:'angular-sanitize',
                settingsModule: 'settingsMasterController',
                ngTagsInput$:'ng-tags-input',
                'chart.js$':'angular-chart.js',
                // Webpack-dev-server dependency
                'inherits':__dirname+'\\..\\node_modules\\inherits',
                n2o: path.resolve('public'),
                ngRoute$: 'angular-route'
            }
        },
        module:  {
            loaders: [{
                // Copy png, jpg, jpeg, gif, svg, woff, woff2, ttf, eot files to output
                // Rename the file using the asset hash
                test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot)/,
                loader: 'file'
            }, {
                // Allow loading html through js
                test: /\.html$/,
                loader: 'raw'
            }, {
              test: /\.css$/,
              loader: "style-loader!css-loader"
            },
            {
              test: /\.json$/,
              loader: "json-loader"
            }]
        },
        plugins: [
          // Make angular variable available, take angular.module() as requires and
          // resolve modules using angular conventions.
          new AngularPlugin()
        ]
    };

    // For using the development mode the webpack-dev-server has to run with
    // following config.
    if(TARGET === 'start-dev-server' || !TARGET) {
      common.output.publicPath = 'http://localhost:9090/app/'
      module.exports = merge(common, {
        devtool: 'eval-source-map',
        debug: true,
        devServer: {
          historyApiFallback: true,
          hot: true,
          inline: true,
          quiet: true,
          host: process.env.HOST,
          port: '9090'
        },
        plugins: [
          new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
        ]
      })
    } else {
      module.exports = merge(common, {
        plugins: [
          new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            minimize: true,
            sourceMap: false,
            mangle: false,
            compress: {
              warnings: false
            }
          })
        ]
      })
    }
```

2. package.json (dependencies)

   ```
   [...]
   "scripts": {
       "compile-production": "webpack --config webpack.config.js",
       "start-dev-server": "webpack-dev-server --config webpack.config.js",
       "start-dev-mode": "start node n2o/app.js & npm run start-dev-server",
       "install-webpack": "npm install webpack@1.12.2 -g & npm install webpack-dev-server@1.14.0 -g",
   [...]
   },
   "dependencies": {
       "MD5": "^1.2.1",
       "adm-zip": "^0.4.7",
       "aws-sdk": "^2.1.34",
       "body-parser": "^1.9.2",
       "bower": "^1.3.1",
       "compression": "^1.5.0",
       "cookie-parser": "^1.3.3",
       "elasticsearch": "^9.0.0",
       "express": "^4.10.1",
       "express-session": "^1.10.2",
       "facebook-node-sdk": "^0.2.0",
       "get-down": "^0.5.0",
       "gnip": "~0.2.1",
       "googlemaps": "^0.1.20",
       "hdb": "^0.4.1",
       "html-pdf": "^1.2.0",
       "json2csv": "^2.2.1",
       "limiter": "^1.0.5",
       "lodash": "^3.7.0",
       "mocha": "~2.2.1",
       "moment": "^2.9.0",
       "morgan": "^1.4.1",
       "multer": "~0.1.8",
       "node-ipc": "^1.1.13",
       "node-tika": "^0.0.1",
       "oauth": "^0.9.12",
       "oauth-request": "0.0.1",
       "passport": "^0.2.2",
       "passport-local": "~1.0.0",
       "phantom": "*",
       "q": "^1.1.2",
       "request": "^2.53.0",
       "response-time": "^2.3.1",
       "sanitize-html": "^1.6.1",
       "string-format": "^0.5.0",
       "stylus": "0.42.3",
       "swig": "^1.4.2",
       "tika": "^1.3.0",
       "tough-cookie": "^0.12.1",
       "twin-bcrypt": "^2.1.1",
       "twit": "^1.1.20",
       "underscore": "~1.8.2",
       "unzip": "^0.1.11",
       "webdriver-manager": "^7.0.1",
       "winston": "^0.9.0"
   },
   "devDependencies": {
       "angular-webpack-plugin": "0.0.3",
       "babel-loader": "^5.3.2",
       "bower-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.8",
       "chai": "^1.10.0",
       "chai-as-promised": "^4.1.1",
       "css-loader": "^0.21.0",
       "css-selector-tokenizer": "^0.5.4",
       "exports-loader": "^0.6.2",
       "file-loader": "^0.8.4",
       "jasmine-node": "~1.14.5",
       "json-loader": "^0.5.2",
       "karma": "^0.12.16",
       "karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.1.4",
       "karma-coverage": "~0.3.1",
       "karma-firefox-launcher": "~0.1.4",
       "karma-jasmine": "^0.1.5",
       "ng-annotate-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.2",
       "protractor": "^1.7.0",
       "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
       "should": "^5.0.0",
       "style-loader": "^0.12.3",
       "supertest": "^0.15.0",
       "webpack": "^1.12.2",
       "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.0",
       "webpack-merge": "^0.3.2"
   }
   [...]
   ```

Comment: node-gyp runs just fine if you take even the slightest effort to install Visual Studio Express and Python, both of which are free. If this is for work, you simply take the time to install them, or you set up a dual boot system and boot to a unix/linux to do the work in. As for the error you found on a clean clone: you probably need to do clean clones more often, or get in the habit of using `rimraf` to delete you node_modules dir and running npm's prune, cache clean, and install (in that order) to make sure only what's in your package.json is installed.

Comment: have you run https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check to see whether you're working with outdated versions of webpack and any of its plugins? Because it's usually a good idea to first move up to the latest versions (which may have fixed your problem already) before trying to dig deeper. Webpack is on v1.12.9 now, for instance. That's already eight patches above what you might be using (depending on how long ago you typed `npm install`)

Comment: I already tried `npm prune` and `npm cache clean`. `npm-check` told me that many dependencies are outdated buts it's not my project and I don't wan't do crash the project right now by changing every dependency - After all it worked everytime until I experimented with webpack.But I tried updating webpack and webpack-dev-server. Didn't change anything. I will try to debug the error. Maybe I can understand the webpack code and find the problem that way.

Comment: I found out that there is an issue caused by the webpack module. I switched from webpack version 1.12.9 to 1.12.1. So webpack now is working but not webpack-dev-server. Same error :/
Source:
Webpack Issue #1713

Comment: nasty.. hopefully you get a good response on the issue tracker!